# ios - cycle for insert array

Tags: ios

Please I need help, I have the following code:

```
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray* params= [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"];

lugar  = params[0];
texto1 = params[1];
texto2 = params[2];
texto3 = params[3];

NSString *query;
query =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CONTENIDO VALUES(null,'%@','%@','%@','%@')", lugar,texto1,texto2,texto3];


// Execute the query.
[self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

// If the query was successfully executed then pop the view controller.
if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
    NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);
}
```

and receive a string text as follows: `34 \ field1 \ DFR23 \ good \ 35 \ field2 \ DFR24 \ good \ 36 \ field3 \ DFR25 \ bad`

My code separates the first four spaces separated by `\` but I need this by inserting a cycle that all spaces are in the array, please could help me?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking? You want all the spaces removed or you want an array of each item separated by spaces?

Comment: I need insert in my db 3 register : 4  field1  DFR23  good  , 35   field2  DFR24  good , 36 field3  DFR25  bad. I need a cycle for but I need a for each to traverse the entire array and insert 3 registers me as I put the code sample that I inserted only the record with id 34

Comment: @antoniker do you mean "loop"? also, this has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: maybe I did not understand in the array I get the web service, is a string using a separator \ , this array I have to go getting and putting in parameters, these the insert into a database, which does not I could do is a cycle along the entire chain and keep saving in these parameters and insert them into sql lite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the stringByAppendingString method that can connect one string to another.

Do something like this:

```
long numberOfSpaces = [params count];

NSString queryString = @"@"INSERT INTO CONTENIDO VALUES(null";
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpaces; i++) {
     NSString *nextParam =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@",//'%@",params[i]];
     queryString = [queryString stringByAppendingString:nextParam;
}
```